# When using MiniProfilter to wrap DbConnection, receive error Procedure or function 'X' expects parameter '@Y', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I am adding MiniProfiler to our existing custom ORM which is based on ADO.Net. [This link](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileSql) indicates that I just need to wrap the DbConnection with a new instance of `ProfiledDbConnection` but when I do that all or most of the queries performed through this connection fail with the message below (or similar, not everything is `ExecuteScalar`). When the DbConnection is no longer wrapped then there is no longer a problem. Is there perhaps an additional step I need to perform for MiniProfiler to work with ADO.Net?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'GetFeature' expects parameter '@Addon', which was not supplied.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

and another example (there are many)

```
Procedure or function 'CampaignInProgress' expects parameter '@CampaignId', which was not supplied.|System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'CampaignContactsInProgressGet' expects parameter '@CampaignId', which was not supplied.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Edit:

`CampaignInProgress` and `GetFeature` are stored procedures. I would like to re-iterate that this is a custom 3rd party ORM which I do not have much detail on. Most of the code shown below is from R# decompilation.

You call the method like:

```
var parms = new List<object>
{
    new GenericParameter(parameterName: "@CampaignId", dbType: DbType.Int64, value: campaignId)
};

using (var ctx = new DbContext(connStr))
{
    ctx.FillWithSp(result, "dbo.CampaignInProgress", parms.ToArray());
}
```

DbContext looks like and was where I added the MiniProfiler wrapper:

```
public DbContext(string connectionStr) : base(ConnectionManager.GetConnection(connectionStr)) { }
```

Next it passes through like so:

```
return Adapter<TDC>().FillWithSP(collection, storedProcedure, parameters);
```

Then:

```
public int FillWithSP(
      ICollection<T> collection,
      string storedProcName,
      params object[] parameters)
    {
      if (storedProcName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (storedProcName));
      return this.FillInternal(collection, storedProcName, FillMethod.StoredProcedure, (IList) parameters);
    }
```

Then

```
private int FillInternal(
      ICollection<T> collection,
      string text,
      FillMethod method,
      IList parameters)
    {
      if (collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (collection));
      if (this.Connection == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("must set connection before calling Fill()");
      using (DbDataReader reader = this.ExecuteReaderInternal(this.PrepCommandForSelect(text, method, parameters), CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
        return this.PopulateCollection(collection, reader);
    }
```

PrepCommandForSelect:

```
private DbCommand PrepCommandForSelect(
      string text,
      FillMethod method,
      IList parameters)
    {
      DbCommand command = (DbCommand) null;
      switch (method)
      {
          // Other cases not relevant
          case FillMethod.StoredProcedure:
          command = this.Connection.CreateCommand();
          command.CommandText = text;
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          DataManager.AddParamsToCommand(command, this.SqlDialect, parameters, this.ParameterPrefix);
          break;
      }
      return command;
    }
```

AddParamsToCommand:

```
public static void AddParamsToCommand(
      DbCommand command,
      SqlDialect dialect,
      IList parameters,
      char placeholderPrefix)
    {
      if (command == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (command));
      if (parameters == null)
        return;
      for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Count; ++index)
      {
        if (parameters[index] is DbParameter)
          command.Parameters.Add(parameters[index]);
        else if (parameters[index] is GenericParameter)
        {
          GenericParameter parameter = (GenericParameter) parameters[index];
          if (parameter.ParameterName == null && command.CommandType == CommandType.Text)
            // Not relevant
          else
            parameter.AddToCommand(command, dialect);
        }
        else if (command.CommandType == CommandType.Text)
        {
          // Not relevant
        }
        else
        {
          // Not relevant
        }
      }
    }
```

AddToCommand

```
public void AddToCommand(DbCommand command, SqlDialect dialect)
    {
      if (command == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (command));
      if (dialect == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (dialect));
      this._nativeParam = command.CreateParameter();
      if (this._parameterName != null || dialect.UseNamedParameters || command.CommandType == CommandType.StoredProcedure)
        this._nativeParam.ParameterName = dialect.FormatParameterName(this._parameterName, command.CommandType);
      this._nativeParam.Direction = this._direction;
      if (this._dbType != DbType.Object)
      {
        if (this._nativeParam is SqlParameter && this._dbType == DbType.Time)
          ((SqlParameter) this._nativeParam).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time;
        else
          this._nativeParam.DbType = this._dbType;
      }
      if (this._size != 0)
        this._nativeParam.Size = this._size;
      this._nativeParam.SourceColumn = this._sourceColumn;
      this._nativeParam.Value = this._value ?? (object) DBNull.Value;
      command.Parameters.Add((object) this._nativeParam);
    }
```

FormatParameterName

```
public override string FormatParameterName(string name, CommandType commandType)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (name));
      return (name[0] == '@' ? name : "@" + name).Replace(' ', '_');
    }
```

Then back to `FillInternal` to method `ExecuteReaderInternal`

```
private DbDataReader ExecuteReaderInternal(
      DbCommand command,
      CommandBehavior behavior)
    {
      this.SetCommandTimeout((IDbCommand) command);
      this.EnrollInTransaction(command);
      this.DoBeforeExecuteCommand(command);
      return command.ExecuteReader(behavior); // System.Data.Common
    }
```

At this point you can pick up from the stack trace. I am not seeing anything that would cause the parameter to be named incorrectly. Keep in mind this code works when it is not wrapped in the MiniProfiler.

Comment: GetFeature and CampaignContactsInProgressGet are the procs of your application?

Comment: Can you show us the source-code of GetFeature and CampaignInProgress?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad I updated the question with as much source code I could find that seemed relevant.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas for the added information. The error messages clearly suggests that some parameters are missing when the stored procedure is called. get_Metadata probably tries to gather metadata and I suppose that you need to investigate what happens there. TryRun attempts to execute your stored procedures. Sounds like some parameter mapping is missing.